# XPath: How to select elements based on their value?

Tags: xpath

I am new to using XPath and this may be a basic question. Kindly bear with me and help me in resolving the issue. I have an XML file like this:

```
<RootNode>
  <FirstChild>
    <Element attribute1="abc" attribute2="xyz">Data</Element>
  <FirstChild>
</RootNode>
```

I can validate the presence of an `<Element>` tag with:

```
//Element[@attribute1="abc" and @attribute2="xyz"]
```

Now I also want to check the value of the tag for string `"Data"`. For achieving this I was told to use:

```
//Element[@attribute1="abc" and @attribute2="xyz" and Data]
```

When I use the later expression I get the following error:

> Assertion failure message: No Nodes Matched `//Element[@attribute1="abc" and @attribute2="xyz" and Data]`

Kindly provide me with your advice whether the XPath expression I have used is valid. If not what will be the valid XPath expression?

Answer (score 368, accepted):

The condition below:

```
//Element[@attribute1="abc" and @attribute2="xyz" and Data]
```

checks for the existence of the element Data within Element and not for element value Data.

Instead you can use

```
//Element[@attribute1="abc" and @attribute2="xyz" and text()="Data"]
```

Answer (score 40):

```
//Element[@attribute1="abc" and @attribute2="xyz" and .="Data"]
```

The reason why I add this answer is that I want to explain the relationship of `.` and `text()` .

First of all, when using `[]`, there are only two types of data:

1. **`[number]`** to select a node from node-set
2. **`[bool]`** to filter a node-set from node-set

In this case, the value is evaluated to boolean by the function `boolean()`, and there is a rule:

> Filters are always evaluated with respect to a context.

When you need to compare `text()` or `.` with a string `"Data"`, it first uses the `string()` function to transform those to string type, then it gets a boolean result.

There are two important rules about `string()`:

1. The `string()` function converts a node-set to a string by returning the string value of the first node in the node-set, which in some instances may yield unexpected results.

   `text()` is relative path that return a node-set contains all the text node of the current node (context node), like `［"Data"］`.
   When it is evaluated by `string(["Data"])`, it will return the first node of the node-set, so you just get "Data" when there only is one text node in the node-set.
2. If you want the `string()` function to concatenate the entire child text, you must pass a single node instead of a node-set.

For example, we get a node-set `['a', 'b']`, you can pass their parent node to `string(parent)`, this will return `'ab'`, and of cause `string(.)` in your case will return an concatenated string `"Data"`.

Both ways will lead to the same result but only when there is a text node.