# How find string xml file and replace with other string( value)

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8

I have problem with my xml  file

```
<OneGoal>
<Goal>80000$ in year</Goal>
<Step>lack content</Step>
<Step>lack content</Step>
<Step>lack content</Step>
<Step>lack content</Step>
<Step>lack content</Step>
<Step>lack content</Step>
<Step>lack content</Step>
<Step>lack content</Step>
<Step>lack content</Step>
<Step>lack content</Step>
<DateDay>17</DateDay>
<DateMonth>6</DateMonth>
<DateYear>2015</DateYear>
</OneGoal>
```

I have comboBox with step from file.  And I have checkBox, wheare I click SelectItemComboBox(Anybody click, SelectFile = "do sport" , and i replace to " remove") must remove step from list and file. How I do ?

Comment: This is pretty unclear as-is. What is it you're looking for, exactly?

Comment: Your combobox loads all <Step> tags from this xml file? And you want to remove one item from combobox and also from the xml file?

Comment: Right @Axarydax. Maybe I add StepOne, StepTwo etc? User choose step for example "lack content" and He checked checkBox. Step remove from combBox and I want in order remove in file xml.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for something like this: [XPath: How to select elements based on their value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198253/xpath-how-to-select-elements-based-on-their-value)

```
Element[@attribute1="abc" and @attribute2="xyz" and text()="Data"]
```

So, try it like

```
/OneGoal/Step[text()="remove"]
```