# Selenium : Find nested div with specific plain text using xpath

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I need to find a certain text in a nested div that has no class or id.

This is a structure of the html.

```
<div class="active_row">
  <div class="outcomes">
   <div class="event_outcome" onclick="doSomething">
     <div>Target Text</div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried accessing the text directly using the example I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198253/xpath-how-to-select-elements-based-on-their-value?rq=1).

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(., 'Target Text')]")
```

This returns a list of elements that contain the target text but nothing happens when I run the click method on them.

What's the best way to set this query to find the text and then click on the div with `event_outcome` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the div with `event_outcome` class, you can add a predicate in your XPath to check class attribute value :

```
//div[contains(., 'Target Text') and @class='event_outcome']
```

or add a predicate to check existence of `onclick` attribute :

```
//div[contains(., 'Target Text') and @onclick]
```

Comment: thanks!!! I combined the two predicates, then printed the result to confirm using `.text`. Now it clicks!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> What's the best way to set this query to find the text and then click on the div with event_outcome class?

You should try using below `xpath` which would returns `<div class="event_outcome" onclick="doSomething">` with text `Target Text` which would fullfil all your needs as below :-

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(., 'Target Text') and @class='event_outcome']")
print(element.text)
element.click()
```

Or you can also get the same with exact match of the inner text using [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) function of the xpath as below :-

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[normalize-space()='Target Text' and @class='event_outcome']")
print(element.text)
element.click()
```

Comment: Lol...thanks! Just did the same thing before seeing your answer. Adding normalize just saved me extra work.